# How to find all in an array of array in MongoDB

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb

Below is the schema for an array contacts. The contacts array has a field hashtag which is another array. How do I find all the contacts which have a particular hashtag? For example all contacts with hashtag "zxc"?

```
"contacts" : [
    {
        "addedDate" : ISODate("2015-12-02T09:06:09.891Z"),
        "personEmailId" : "tell.fadgfdg@gmail.com",
        "_id" : ObjectId("565eb481bf35eeb83d7f9f13"),
        "verified" : true,
        "favorite" : true,
        "linkedinUserName" : null,
        "facebookUserName" : null,
        "twitterUserName" : "IamlifePaul",
        "count" : 2,
        "relationshipStrength_updated" : 0,
        "contactRelation" : {
            "decisionmaker_influencer" : null,
            "prospect_customer" : "prospect"
        },
        "source" : "abc",
        "mobileNumber" : "3546789",
        "skypeId" : "123",
        "designation" : "test",
        "companyName" : "Something",
        "location" : "Hyderabad, Telangana, India",
        "personName" : "Naveen Paul",
        "personId" : "565022d7dbeaeb9e17fc7083",
        "hashtag" : [

            "latestTag",
            "anotherTag",
            "#hash",
            "openLove",
            "hellTwo",
            "working?",
            "hello",
            "lol",
            "zxc"
        ],
        "lastInteracted" : ISODate("2015-12-08T05:07:53.746Z")
    },
{
        "addedDate" : ISODate("2015-12-02T09:06:09.891Z"),
        "personEmailId" : "naveenpaul.fadgfdg@gmail.com",
        "_id" : ObjectId("565eb481bf35eeb83d7f9f13"),
        "verified" : true,
        "favorite" : true,
        "linkedinUserName" : null,
        "facebookUserName" : null,
        "twitterUserName" : "IamlifePaul",
        "count" : 2,
        "relationshipStrength_updated" : 0,
        "contactRelation" : {
            "decisionmaker_influencer" : null,
            "prospect_customer" : "prospect"
        },
        "source" : "abc",
        "mobileNumber" : "3546789",
        "skypeId" : "123",
        "designation" : "test",
        "companyName" : "Something",
        "location" : "Hyderabad, Telangana, India",
        "personName" : "Naveen Paul",
        "personId" : "565022d7dbeaeb9e17fc7083",
        "hashtag" : [

            "latestTag",
            "anotherTag",
            "#hash",
            "openLove",
            "hellTwo",
            "working?",
            "hello",
            "lol",
            "zxc"
        ],
        "lastInteracted" : ISODate("2015-12-08T05:07:53.746Z")
    },
{
        "addedDate" : ISODate("2015-12-02T09:06:09.891Z"),
        "personEmailId" : "naveenpaul.fadgfdg@gmail.com",
        "_id" : ObjectId("565eb481bf35eeb83d7f9f13"),
        "verified" : true,
        "favorite" : true,
        "linkedinUserName" : null,
        "facebookUserName" : null,
        "twitterUserName" : "IamlifePaul",
        "count" : 2,
        "relationshipStrength_updated" : 0,
        "contactRelation" : {
            "decisionmaker_influencer" : null,
            "prospect_customer" : "prospect"
        },
        "source" : "abc",
        "mobileNumber" : "3546789",
        "skypeId" : "123",
        "designation" : "test",
        "companyName" : "Something",
        "location" : "Hyderabad, Telangana, India",
        "personName" : "Naveen Paul",
        "personId" : "565022d7dbeaeb9e17fc7083",
        "hashtag" : [

            "polly",
            "tagger",
            "#hash",
            "working?",
            "hello",
            "lol",
            "zxc"
        ],
        "lastInteracted" : ISODate("2015-12-08T05:07:53.746Z")
    }
```

I did this query - `db.myColl.find({"contacts.hashtag":"zxc"},{"contacts":{$elemMatch:{"hashtag":"zxc"}}}).pretty()`
 which returned only one contact. I need to get all contacts.

Comment: which modeling package do you use here? mongoose?

Comment: Yes, I'm using Mongoose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it via aggregation framework:

1) Do an initial match to reduce the input set for aggregation

2) Unwind contacts field.

3) Filter out contacts with hashtag 'zxc'

4) Group by id and put contacts on "contacts" field.

```
db.getCollection('contacts').aggregate([
    {$match: {"contacts.hashtag":"zxc"}},
    {$unwind: "$contacts"},
    {$match: {"contacts.hashtag":"zxc"}},
    {$group: {_id:"$_id", "contacts": {$push:"$contacts"}}}
])
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

**For multiple hashtag in single doc**

```
db.myColl.find({"contacts.hashtag":{$in : ['zxc','anotherTag']}});
//will return all doc with any of the two hashtags.
```

**For single hashtag**

```
   db.myColl.find({"contacts.hashtag":'zxc'});
  //return all documents with hashtag 'zxc'
```

Please refer [$in](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/query/in/)

Comment: This returns all the documents. Even without the hashtags.

Comment: Without the hashtags means a document without the hashtags property?? Above will not return those document !! Please explain?

Comment: Its returning all the contacts without the hashtag ''zxc" or without the hashtag property. Coz some contacts don't have any hashtags and thus the hashtag field is not yet created for them.